# static instance variable pass by value

Tags: java, static, parameter-passing

I thought static primitive variables in java should work differently than non-static when passed to a method:

```
public class Main {

    private static int a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        modify(a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    static void modify(int a){ 
        a++;
    }
}
```

The output is 0 which is understandable for primitives passed by value, but why static doesn't mean anything here? I would expect 1 as an output.

Maybe a silly question but I am confused.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 2):

The name `a` in your `modify` method is referring to the local method parameter, not the `static` variable.

Comment: so how to access an 'a' instance variable from modify()? You can't use 'this' in static context right?

Comment: @jarosik You can qualify it. `Main.a`.

Comment: Other valid solution I came up with: you can just rename the method argument to: modify (int b) or anything else than 'a' and the plain 'a++' would work.

Comment: @jarosik The concept is known as _scope_.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a shadowing variable in your static method
when `a++` get executed it will increase the value of that method local variable by 1

static variable default value is 0 and will not get affect.

if you want that to be changed
use

```
Main.a++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you could solve this by an int wrapper, like `AtomicInteger`:

```
public class Main {

    private static final AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        modify(a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    static void modify(AtomicInteger  a){ 
        a.getAndIncrement(); // "eqvivalent" of a++
    }
}
```

Your current code, takes an int, and because how Java works, it recieves a copy of your `static a`, and has no effect on your static field.